# MVC Asynchronous call

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous

As new developer to MVC I am confused about how this will work: I need two post actions inside a controller. 
1. One asynchronous (file data and auth headers in body request). This will upload a file to server and returns the file's path/name on server 
2. One synchronous. This is fired by the submit button of my view and should wait the previous call to assure we uploaded the file.

My view should have two Html.BeginForm one for each action? Or the Html.BeginForm is one for the submit button and the asynchronous call is implemented by jQuery?

Comment: It really depends on you project and need. There are multiple approaches possible. Two forms on the same page, everything handled using AJAX calls, mixed mode where you are using form post and asynchronous AJAX calls. Provide more details...

Answer (score 1):

First, there's some confusion here about async. In the context of a web request, async merely means that the thread handling the request can be returned to the pool if it enters a wait-state. This is usually due to some sort of I/O (database query, HTTP request, file system access, etc.). The determination of whether to use async or not boils down to whether there will be any period where the active thread will be "waiting" on something.

Now, as to your form, it really depends on what exactly you are doing here. Especially being new to this, you should really approach questions from the standpoint of "I need to do X", rather than "I've decided I'm going to accomplish something via either Y or Z". In the latter, Y and Z may be completely wrong approaches to X, but we have no way of knowing that or advising you differently.

For example, why do you need two actions? A single action can both post data and upload a file or files. In fact, it makes far more sense to handle it this way as then you're no longer dependent on one action waiting for the completion of another. The only reason I could see for want to handling the two separately is so you could display a preview of an uploaded image, for example, but even then, the correct approach is to use the File API in JavaScript and still just do one post.

Comment: Finally did it with single action. Thanks.